# Отличие частиц "то" и "же"

Tags: частицы

В толковых словарях даются следующие определения частицам "то" и "же":

1. Частица "**-то**" употребляется для подчёркивания и выделения в предложении слова, к которому относится.
2. Частица "**же**" употребляется для усиления, подчеркивания значения слова, после которого ставится, а также для усиления смыслового содержания всего высказывания.
   Получается, что по смыслу (определению) эти частицы практически одинаковые, но разница есть. И возникает вопрос - чем они отличаются функционально? Особенно непонятно про частицу "же" - каким образом она усиливает смысловое содержание.

Comment: Попробую привести пример: "ты сделал уроки?" и "ты же сделал уроки?" - немного разный смысл. во втором случае `же` даже может показывать ожидаемый ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Глубокий вопрос.
Профессор Зализняк интересную [статью](https://elementy.ru/nauchno-populyarnaya_biblioteka/431049/Nekotorye_problemy_poryadka_slov_v_istorii_russkogo_yazyka) написал на счет особенностей частицы **же**. Я даже и подумать не мог, что там столько глубинных закономерностей.

> Энклитики по смыслу могут быть двух сортов. Одни относятся к конкретному слову, например русское то: где-то, кто-то, куда-то. Они представляют собой некоторое уточнение предшествующего слова. Другие имеют более общее значение и относятся к фразе в целом. Или, если говорить более техническим языком, относятся к сказуемому как центру фразы. Это, например, частицы же или бы для современного русского языка. Даже если такое слово стоит очень далеко от глагола, оно всё равно относится по смыслу именно к нему, например: я бы никогда ни при каких условиях ни за что этого не сказал. От бы до сказал огромное расстояние, и тем не менее, как вы понимаете, бы относится к сказуемому. Оно переводит всю фразу из изъявительного наклонения в сослагательное. Тем самым уточняется смысл фразы в целом.
>
> Соответственно, мы будем говорить об энклитиках локальных, которые
> относятся к соседнему слову (предшествующему), и об энклитиках
> фразовых, которые относятся к фразе в целом. Повторяю, что на самом
> деле технически — к сказуемому. Интересовать нас будут именно фразовые
> энклитики, потому что с ними связаны наиболее интересные
> закономерности.

Также существует две совершенно разных по смыслу, функциям (и написанию в древнем языке) частицы **же**

> Но есть и другое же, отождествительное (как в такое же, тот же самый,
> там же, к тому же), — это локальная энклитика. Мы сейчас с трудом
> различаем эти два же. Но на самом деле они совершенно разного
> происхождения. По-старославянски одно из них же, а другое жде, так что
> это просто чистое совпадение двух разных единиц. Они и ведут себя до
> сих пор совершенно по-разному.

Comment: Единственно не понятно - частица "же" может усиливать значение слова после которого стоит или перед которым стоит, а может она работает в обе стороны?

Comment: Прочитайте внимательно лекцию Зализняка, она адаптирована для школьников. Там проясняется куча вопросов именно по частице "же". В моей же цитате написан ответ на ваш последний вопрос. Частица "же" всегда относится к фразе целиком (к глаголу), а не к какому-то слову рядом с которым она написана. Но есть и совершенно другая частица "же". Она относится именно к словам (локальное же). О ней тоже упоминается в статье. Это раньше были два разных слова

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Все ясно!